# What does "Remote Styles Cache" option of GeoServer do?

Tags: geoserver

There is no information about the parameter in the GeoServer documentation.

Can you explain what happens when the parameter is activated and will it speed up the work with a large number of layers?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It caches remote styles (see the [issue](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8827)) - unless you are importing a lot of styles from remote sources it is unlikely to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

WMS Service supports reading rendering styles from an external source by including parameter `&SLD=` in the GetMap request. It is documented in version 1.1.1 of the WMS standard as

> SLD=styled_layer_descriptor_URL
>
> O (optional)
>
> URL of Styled Layer Descriptor (as defined in SLD Specification).

Caching the remote SLD styles means that GeoServer can get them from the local cache instead of requesting them every time though internet. If you and your users do not use remote styles then activating this option does not give you any speed up.